# Setting the system time of JVM

Tags: java, unix, systemtime

I have a java app which runs on a linux/unix machine.

When setting the system time via system command, on the console using date I see that the date/time has changed, but it seems as my JVM didn't recognize this change.

It seems that this is not a rights problem, because in the shell I see that the date/time has changed. Only my JVM didn't recognize this change.

Any hints where to search ?

Comment: How did you check if the VM had noticed the change?

Comment: I'm sorry, this isn't really on-topic here. SO is for programming questions. This question would be a better fit on SuperUser.

Comment: @Keppil: i checked it via commandline that the date/time has changed. but in the vm, by example a logger is running and reports are generated, they are using the old date. and i have no clue why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/302396/how-to-set-current-time-on-linux) over on the super user stack exchange. There are 2 different clocks in linux. One is hardware (hwclock) and the other is os/system.